# Sencha Touch 2 app doesn't work on mini iPad

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, ipad-mini

I have created a Sencha Touch 2 application and packaged it for iOS after doing the required provisioning in the apple portal. The application gets installed and works fine on all iOS devices except for iPad minis, although the "deviceType" in the packager.json file is set to "Universal". Could this be a bug in ST2 SDK where iPad minis are not supported? if not, what workarounds can do it?